# What is the best way to implement File Authentication in Java?

Tags: java, security

By file authentication, I mean reading a file and then authenticating it. 
Do I need the Java security library?

I have already tried to google this but I'm not sure and I don't have a background in security.

Comment: Depends what you mean by authentic?

Comment: Let's say the user enters a username and password in the file and we need to see that user is valid.

Comment: you would compare the input with what you have stored in your database. You would need to hash the inputted password before comparing since you (hopefully) store hashes

Comment: Storing username and password in a file is a bad idea.